# How to find out if a user without an email address tried to reset his password

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I thought to use the **Custom message** hook (*triggerSource = "CustomMessage_ForgotPassword"*), but this hook won't even be invoked unless the target user had an email address.

What is the right hook for such a case?

Comment: Does user have a phone number?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately, the users don't have this information.